# multiple CDN bundle in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, bundle

I have been trying to bundle all js files from CDN into a single bundle like so:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
string cdnHost = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/";
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularCDN", cdnHost).Include(
                        "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js",
                        "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-cookies.js",
                        "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-route.js"));
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

But i keep getting "angular is undefined"..  and when i view source the page only loads the main CDN url : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/"></script>`

I also tried to set the debug = false.

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the cdnHost parameter refers to alternate URL for the bundle when it is stored in a content delivery network. The cdn boundle is supposed to be loaded as one file and should contain a combined content of all files uploaded on cdn (will be just `https://ajax.googleapis.com/` in your case):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularCDN", cdnHost).Include(
                        "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js",
                        "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-cookies.js",
                        "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular-route.js"));
```

basically you have three options:

- define multiple bundles one per each resource "~/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js" and the version hosted on cdn
- do not use the cdnHost parameter
- combine all files manually and upload them on custom cdn then use this cdn as cdnHost

Comment: "The cdn boundle is supposed to be loaded as one file and should contain a combined content of all files uploaded on cdn" --> really ? that's so inconvenient.

Comment: @MajoB In that case what would .Include() do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jsdelivr (see https://github.com/jsdelivr/jsdelivr).

For example, if you want to bundle AngularJS 1.2.19, you can use the following:

```
 var angularBundleCdnPath = "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/angularjs@1.2.19(angular.min.js+angular-route.min.js+angular-animate.min.js+angular-cookies.min.js)";

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular",
                    angularBundleCdnPath).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-animate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-cookies.js"));
```